# SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

How can I fix this?

SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(near "@gmail": syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = sonerbascifcii@gmail.com password = son123, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = sonerbascifcii@gmail.com password = son123' args [])

This is the code i came across.

```
  static Future<User> getLoginUser(String email, String password) async {
final db = await instance.database;
var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $users WHERE "
    "${UserTitle.email} = $email "
    "${UserTitle.password} = $password");

if (result.isNotEmpty) {
  return User.fromJson(result.first);
} else {
  return throw Exception('get LoginUser kısmında hata');
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a quote issue and a missing logical operator issue in your SQL resquest, try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = 'sonerbascifcii@gmail.com' AND password = 'son123'
```

**IMPORTANT**

**Avoid** use of unencrypted password, is is a security issue. You **should** encrypted your password and compare encrypted password, not clear ones.

You should also use parameter query to avoid SQL injection:

```
var result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $users WHERE ${UserTitle.email} = ? AND ${UserTitle.password} = ? ", [$email, $password]);
```

Comment: thanks :) ı fix that. But one more question. When I run it on mobile it works fine, but when I run it on windows [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: type 'MissingPluginException' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
#0 _RegisterScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> I encountered such a problem.

Comment: This problem seem to be different from this one. I% suggest you to open a news topic about it. Don't forget to provide source code, error text ...